# c#, Graphics.DrawString(), InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, graphics

Столкнулся с **InvalidOperationException**: В данный момент объект используется другим процессом.

У меня есть форма и таймер, который ее обновляет.

Исключение возникает через некоторое время **только** при вызове метода **Graphics.DrawString()** с любыми аргументами.

Текст исключения:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: В данный момент объект используется другим процессом.
в System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
в System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString(String s, Font font, Brush brush, RectangleF layoutRectangle, StringFormat format)
в System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString(String s, Font font, Brush brush, Single x, Single y)
в WindowsFormsApplication5.Display.Display_Paint(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e) в C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Display.cs:строка 33
в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
в System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
в System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
в System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
в System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Это при том, что потоки я не использую. По всей видимости в формах по дефолту есть два потока, которые одновременно просят перерисовать форму.

Форма:

```
    public partial class Display : Form {

        private double x, y;
        private long time;

        public Display() {
            Bundle.init();
            InitializeComponent();
            DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void Display_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                g.DrawString("Test", Bundle.menuFont, Brushes.Black, Width / 2 - 195, Height / 2 + 55);
        }
    }
```

Ресурсы:

```
 public class Bundle {
    public static Bitmap logo { get; set; }
    public static Bitmap background { get; set; }
    public static Font menuFont { get; set; }

    public static Bitmap wall { get; set; }
    public static Bitmap floor { get; set; }
    public static Bitmap car { get; set; }
    public static Bitmap[] oil { get; set; }
    public static Bitmap oilpath { get; set; }

    public static void init() {
        logo = new Bitmap("../../Images/logo.png");
        background = new Bitmap("../../Images/background.png");

        PrivateFontCollection f = new PrivateFontCollection();
        f.AddFontFile("../../Images/Upheaval.otf");
        menuFont = new Font(f.Families[0], 24);
    }
}
```

Почему я ловлю исключение именно после вызова DrawString()? Все остальные методы Graphics работают идеально.

Как решить эту проблему? Она очень сильно мешает.

Comment: Нет, двух потоков нету. Ошибка где-то в другом месте.

Comment: Есть, я создал переменную timer для проверки со значением 0.
Увеличивал при входе в paint() и уменьшал при выходе.
В блоке try catch она оказалась равной 2.

Comment: Ну и каким образом это говорит о многопоточности? Попробуйте в начале `Display_Paint` вывести `Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)`.

Comment: Действительно... Выводит 1 все время... Это очень странно. Откуда тогда появляется ошибка.

Comment: А вот интересно. То есть у вас приходил Paint рекурсивно, внутри другого Paint'а? Попробуйте посмотреть, на какой именно из операций вызвался «вложенный» Paint.

Comment: Не имею ни малейшего понятия о том, где он может возникнуть.

Comment: Ну так вы покажите stack trace «внутреннего» Paint'а.

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что Paint вызывается рекурсивно? Не бы рад, но не могу понять.

Comment: Ну у вас же где-то переменная `timer` имела значение 2? Ну вот, поскольку мы в одном потоке, это может быть только если Paint вызывается внутри себя рекурсивно. Попробуйте что-то такое: `if (timer > 0) { /*тут breakpoint*/ } timer++; тут весь Paint; timer--;`

Comment: Ок. Завтра сделаю отладку. Кстати говоря, поставил TextRenderer.DrawText() - он идеально работает.